# Make button do something different on each click

Tags: jquery

I want the same button to display different images with each click so first click will display image one and second click will display image two and so on...

Comment: What did you do so far ?

Comment: nothing, all ideas. tried to change ID and class but always had the impression you can always click several times and when encountered I thought there would be something to segment clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a counter that exists outside the onClick() call that would increment on every click. Something like,

```
<button onclick="onClick()">Change Image</button>

<script language="JavaScript">

    var count = 0;
    var n = 10; //arbitrary number of images

    function onClick() {

        if (count === 0) {
            //change image source to first image
            document.getElementById("imageElement").src="image1.png";
        } else if (count === 1) {
            //change image source to second image
            document.getElementById("imageElement").src="image2.png";
        }
        //repeat as necessary for number of images

        count += 1;

        //reset count when image limit is reached
        if (count === n)
            count = 0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: providing how to change src of img would be nice too.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to the mentioned scenario could be to set up a JavaScript counter and placing an if condition underneath. Within the if check which number it is currently at, update the image div Url accordingly as well as updating the counter to + 1.